# Server not found when redirect tinyurl to original url, only slug isshown in the address bar

Tags: python, django, redirect

I am trying to create short urls for products. The short urls are generated and rendered successfully to the templates.

After I got my short URL, i copied it and search it in the browser, It says Server Not Found.
**I want to redirect those short urls to original urls**

For ex: My original url is  - **127.0.0.1:8000/affiliation/link/10002/**,
and its own short url is - **tinyurl.com/yze3sjse**; when i copy short url and search it on the browser, only the slug part is shown in the browser, i.e. **affiliation/link/10002/** and Hence , it cannot redirect to original url

This is my functions :

Views.py

```
#Display individual product and render short links for all using pyshorteners
def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
    slink = request.get_full_path()
    shortener = pyshorteners.Shortener()
    short_link = shortener.tinyurl.short(slink)
    return render(request, 'link.html', {"results": results, "short_link": short_link})
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('link/', views.link, name='link'),
    path('link/<int:uid>/', views.link_view, name='link_view')
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also the address bar in the browser shows: 'affiliation/link/10004/', the localhost has been missed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last sentence say everything.

You are trying to access to `affiliation/link/10004/` which doesn't exist.

You forget to put the DNS/IP (in your case: localhost), like: `http://mywebsite.com/affiliation/link/10004/`

For me, the issue come from `request.get_full_path()` which only return the URL content, not the full address.

Comment: do request.get_absolute_uri would work?
**The short url which is being created doesnt get back to original url**

Comment: I think yes, for me you should try

Comment: request.get_absolute_uri, sends back attribute error.

Comment: The tinyurl is **https:/tinyurl.com/yze3sjse** and i want this url to redirect to **http:/127.0.0.1:8000/affiliation/link/10002/**; which is not happening

Note: I have changed the urls for security reasons

Comment: Yes but the given tinyurl redirect to only to content avec the IP. So your tinyurl is wrong, you forget the `http://127.0.0.1:8000` at the beginning

Comment: So how can i achieve that?

Comment: When you create tinyurl, you have to fon't forget to keep the beginning section. And such as I don't know your full code, I don't know how you can do exactly

Comment: Hi, so is that fine now ?

Comment: Ok :) if it's me Who help you, can you accept my answer ? Else, you can self-answer to share how you fix it

Answer (score 1):

Below Function converts the URL to desired short links as you need:

```
#Display individual product and render short links for all using pyshorteners
def link_view(request, user_id, uid):
    user_id = user_id
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
    slink = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" + request.get_full_path()
    shortener = pyshorteners.Shortener()
    short_link = shortener.tinyurl.short(slink)
    return render(request, 'link.html', {"results": results, "short_link": short_link, "user_id": user_id})
```